# Button used for redirecting, with a php function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to redirect to a page with a button. I do not want to use the headers function. I want to be able to call some function inside a php file. 
My function for redirecting looks something like this. Basicly the first part set what page to load in a static variable and then executes a reload of page which then executes the load function in some other initialization function.

This can be modified, its just how i taught of doing it.

```
public function WSP_Redirect($site)
{
    self::$_mainsite = $site;

            //This is one option 
    //$this->LoadPage();

            // This is another option
    echo '<script>window.location.reload()</script>';

}
```

The in another file i would, say press a button, and the button would then call this function(via post or whatever) to redirect to some page...

To me its not important how it is done but it is important that it uses the redirect function.

Any suggestions would be nice, I did check out the ajax and jquery but nothing i have tryed has worked so far :(

Comment: why don't you want to use headers? It's by far the best and most correct way.

Comment: please explain the higher level logic in more detail. Can likely do this all in javascript

Comment: You could try include() or require()

Comment: you _must_ use headers for this, users with javascript disabled wouldn't be redirected using this approach

Comment: Well im trying to use require, so that i do not jump from page to page, but stay on one index page and include stuff inside there depending on the redirects.

Comment: The higher logic is that i have, say rootdir/index.php  in this index.php i have an initialize function which executes the loadpage function, that actually require_once's some other php page with the actual html objects.

Comment: doesn't explain anything about button logic

Comment: Redirecting means going to another page. In your case, if I understand correctly, you are trying to make a single-page application. You should use a JavaScript framework for this.

Comment: Let say i have somethin like a menu button or login button, so i would like when i click the button, to go to homepage, or any other page, and maybe when i click a login button i want to first validate data and then redirect to the user profile. Something like that.

Comment: Well yeah thats what im trying to do, a single-page application :D Yeah, maybe the redirecting is not the best choice of a word but i dont know how else to call it.

Comment: Do you maybe know how does Joomla access or work with pages ?

Answer (score 0):

how about using

```
 header('Location: ' . $site);
```

directly from PHP ?

Comment: Dont want to do that, trying to find another way :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, why you don't use headers, but in JavaScript you could do it like this:

```
<script>window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"</script>
```

So in your PHP file, it would be something like this:

```php
public function WSP_Redirect($site) {
    ...
    echo '<script>window.location = "' . $site . '"</script>';
}
```

Comment: I dont want to go from www.page.com/page1.php to www.page.com/page2.php but would like to stay on www.page.com/index.php and just include/uninclude pages inside that.